# SSRS: Time Out for Timeouts! Stop the Drops! A Cause for the Causes, Just Because

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2016, ssrs-2016

I realize that SQL Server 2016 RC1 and all of its RC1-refreshed accessories may be half-baked.

That said, let me ask this:  In SSRS, what may be causing flaky connectivity and timeouts?

No default-installation timeout settings (wherever I found them...SSMS server connection, SSRS query/report setting, etc.) have been lowered.  On the contrary, to troubleshoot this issue, they have been doubled or trebled.  SQL-related services are all running, and firewall ports are open wide:

```
SQL Server - Firewall Settings - Inbound

TCP/IP
Port    Description
====    ======================================================
80      SQL Server Reporting Services Web Services
443     SQL Server Reporting Services Mobile Reports via HTTPS
135     SQL Server Transact-SQL Debugger/RPC
1433    SQL Server Default Instance
1434    SQL Server Admin Connection
2382    SQL Server Browser
2383    SQL Server Analysis Services
4022    SQL Server Service Broker

UDP
Port    Description
====    ======================================================
1434    SQL Server Browser Multicast Response
```

Symptoms:

(1)  Often, I cannot save a simple report.  Even though the Status Bar shows a "Current report server http://XXX/ReportServer" connection, the crazy, on-save-attempt error states that "http://XXX:80/ReportServer" (notice that it adds the ":80") is unknown.  I will restart SS-related services, and that seems to make a difference, for a short time.

(2) A simple, boring SELECT — that flies in SSMS — times out when used as the dataset for a report run via the SSRS Web portal or Report Builder.  Even the prompt for ONE parameter (against a tiny lookup dataset) takes a couple of minutes to appear, while that same lookup logic (another boring, trivial SELECT) flies in SMSS.  (Once the parameter is chosen, the aforementioned timeout is the result.)

Microsoft's useless, cryptic timeout messages appear as follows:

For Save or Save As:

```
"The wait operation timed out at 
Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ReportingService2010Impl.CreateReport..."
```

Oh, good, some ASPy error trash, with no clues on how to fix the problem.

For Save or Save As:

```
"The report 'http://XXX:80/ReportServer/Test' contains a reference to a 
data source that is not valid. Verify that the shared data sources and 
models that are required for this report are deployed to the report server."
```

I went back into the respective property pages for the datasets and re-selected/refreshed them from the same report server where they have lain undisturbed and remain fully functional (tested via the Preview menu choice on the report server).

For Run:

```
"The operation has timed out.  Details:  The operation has timed out."
```

Gee, thanks, Captain Obvious.

For Run:

```
"Failed to preview report.  An error occurred within the report server 
database.  This may be due to a connection failure, timeout, or low disk 
condition within the database.  Details: ...The wait operation timed out at 
Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ReportingService2005Impl.SetReportDefinition..."
```

Well, there is plenty of disk space.

For Run:

```
"The report execution md0spy55neszejbw04zqwq45 has expired or cannot be found.
(rsExecutionNotFound)"
```

What are the best ways to keep SSRS's connection persistent so that I may save my reports without issue and run them without watching them crawl and then time out?

Comment: it suggests you have locking,blockings

Comment: I am the only one touching the entire SS installation — and only via reporting, after checking in SSMS both the syntax and execution time of the simple SELECTs.